# this error comes up when trying to install rails. How do I change the path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### I am installing rails, but it won't progress past this point, how do I know where to send it?

> /usr/bin/rails:22:in `load': cannot load such file -- /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby->2.2.1@global/gems/railties-4.1.7/bin/rails (LoadError)
>     from /usr/bin/rails:22:in`'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me the other day. If I remember correctly it was an issue with Ruby 2.2.1.

RVM into a lower version of ruby, install rails, then switch back.